# What does it mean when a diagram "commutes to homotopy"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, category-theory, definition

[image]

What does commutes in $hTop_*$ mean and how does the proof following this sentence show it?

The proof says this follows from $q_1m \simeq 1_x \simeq q_2m$ where $q_1, q_2 : X \lor X \rightarrow X$ are defined as projections that send $x$ to $(x,x_0)$ or $(x_0,x)$, respectively and $X \lor X$ is viewed as the subspace of $X \times \{x_0\} \cup \{x_0\} \times X$.

Comment: The diagram would commute if $k\circ m=\Delta$. Commuting up to homotopy means here that $k\circ m \simeq \Delta$.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the functions $\Delta$ and $k \circ m$ are (base-point preserving) homotopic.

Comment: How does the proof in the question show that this is true?  It looks like we can't assume that $\Delta=k \circ m$ but how would we show the homotopy relationship?

Comment: Recall that the cartesian product is the categorical product in $\mathcal{T}_*$. The wedge inclusion is the unique map $k:X\vee X\rightarrow X\times X$ satisfying $pr_1\circ k=q_1$, $pr_2\circ k=q_2$. Thus $k\circ m$ is the unique map $X\rightarrow X\times X$ satisfying $pr_1\circ (k\circ m)= (pr_1\circ k)\circ m=q_1\circ m$ and $pr_2\circ (k\circ m)=q_2\circ m$.  Now the diagonal is the unique map $\Delta: X\rightarrow X\times X$ satisfying $pr_1\circ\Delta=id_X=pr_2\circ\Delta$. We get $pr_i\circ(k\circ m)\simeq pr_i\circ \Delta$ and conclude the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to seeing it as (and would write it as) "commutes up to a homotopy". The phrase 'up to an X' means we are setting a weaker standard for equality than strict equality. I've also seen it used in the phrase "$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ is the same as $\mathbb{Z}_6$ (up to a group isomorphism)".